# How do I stop CPAN from accessing an unresponsive package repository?

Tags: perl, cpan

I tried to install a package. It's failing connecting to `soft-download.org`. I don't know why it's trying to connect to that host.

```
$ cpan install Config::IniFiles
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.53_01)
Reading '/home/Chloe/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sat, 24 Dec 2016 20:17:02 GMT
Running install for module 'Config::IniFiles'
CPAN: LWP::UserAgent loaded ok (v6.15)
CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.9732)
Fetching with LWP:
http://soft-download.org/authors/id/S/SH/SHLOMIF/Config-IniFiles-2.94.tar.gz
LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to soft-download.org:80]

Trying with
    /usr/bin/wget -O "/home/Chloe/.cpan/sources/authors/id/S/SH/SHLOMIF/Config-IniFiles-2.94.tar.gz.tmp11320"
to get
    http://soft-download.org/authors/id/S/SH/SHLOMIF/Config-IniFiles-2.94.tar.gz
--2016-12-24 16:19:24--  http://soft-download.org/authors/id/S/SH/SHLOMIF/Config-IniFiles-2.94.tar.gz
Resolving soft-download.org (soft-download.org)... 204.45.81.83
Connecting to soft-download.org (soft-download.org)|204.45.81.83|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2016-12-24 16:19:46--  (try: 2)  http://soft-download.org/authors/id/S/SH/SHLOMIF/Config-IniFiles-2.94.tar.gz
Connecting to soft-download.org (soft-download.org)|204.45.81.83|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2016-12-24 16:20:09--  (try: 3)  http://soft-download.org/authors/id/S/SH/SHLOMIF/Config-IniFiles-2.94.tar.gz
Connecting to soft-download.org (soft-download.org)|204.45.81.83|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

I tried to reload the index, but it still tries to access `soft-download.org`.

```
cpan[2]> reload index
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.53_01)
Reading '/home/Chloe/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sat, 24 Dec 2016 20:17:02 GMT
CPAN: LWP::UserAgent loaded ok (v6.15)
CPAN: Time::HiRes loaded ok (v1.9732)
Fetching with LWP:
http://soft-download.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[500] message[Can't connect to soft-download.org:80]

Trying with
    /usr/bin/wget -O "/home/Chloe/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp14304"
to get
    http://soft-download.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
--2016-12-24 16:27:15--  http://soft-download.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Resolving soft-download.org (soft-download.org)... 204.45.81.83
Connecting to soft-download.org (soft-download.org)|204.45.81.83|:80...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution 1: Remove the bad repository

Run `cpan` with no arguments, then enter

```
o conf urllist
```

This is will lists the repositories to use.

```
urllist
    0 [http://good1/]
    1 [http://good2/]
    2 [http://bad/]
```

Re-enter the repositories without the bad one as follows:

```
o conf urllist http://good1/ http://good2/
```

Finally, save your changes as follows:

```
o conf commit
```

### Solution 2: Find the repositories that are the fastest for you

Run `cpan` with no arguments, then enter

```
o conf init urllist
```

When asked "Would you like me to automatically choose some CPAN mirror
sites for you?", press Enter.

Finally, save your changes as follows:

```
o conf commit
```

### Solution 3: Find repositories by region

Run `cpan` with no arguments, then enter

```
o conf init urllist
```

When asked "Would you like me to automatically choose some CPAN mirror
sites for you?", enter `no`.

When asked "Would you like to edit the urllist or pick new mirrors from a list?", press Enter.

When asked "Shall I use the cached mirror list?", enter `no`.

Select mirrors as directed by the prompt.

Finally, save your changes as follows:

```
o conf commit
```

Answer (score 9):

```
cpan[5]> o conf urllist
    urllist
        0 [http://soft-download.org/]
        1 [http://cpan.develooper.com/]
        2 [http://cpan.erlbaum.net/]

cpan[10]> o conf urllist http://cpan.erlbaum.net http://cpan.develooper.com
Please use 'o conf commit' to make the config permanent!


cpan[11]> o conf urllist
    urllist
        0 [http://cpan.erlbaum.net]
        1 [http://cpan.develooper.com]
Type 'o conf' to view all configuration items


cpan[12]> o conf commit
commit: wrote '/home/Chloe/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm'
```

http://www.cpan.org/SITES.html